# How can I eat in peaceful mode?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

How do I eat in peaceful mode? I won't lose any hunger. Is there a way I can lose hunger in peaceful without monsters spawning.

I'm playing on Xbox 360.

Comment: Not possible. Peaceful mode was meant to be peaceful, with no major hardships (mobs, hunger, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can't lose hunger in peaceful mode, therefore, you can't eat anything, and you don't need to too.